# Passing very long double values in mysqli_query misbehave

Tags: php, mysql, double

I would like to retrieve from my database all the records in a specific range. The query is like that

```
$query = "select * from user_tags where user_tags.lon>'$left' and user_tags.lon<'$right' and user_tags.lat<'$top' and user_tags.lat>'$bottom'";
```

and the values the vars contains are like -24.989144280552864 and 8.673474003099022

The problem is that if I execute the query in the mysql cmd it retruns the records but when it is being executed from php i get null...

Any ideas what is happening with the php? It can not hold so large values or negatives?
Thanks!

EDIT: the full execution code

```
if($region === "3"){

$query = "select * from user_tags where user_tags.lon>'$left' and user_tags.lon<'$right' and user_tags.lat<'$top' and user_tags.lat>'$bottom'";
$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die(mysqli_error());//mysql_query($query);//mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($data) > 0) {         
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data))//mysqli_fetch_array
        {
            $lat = $row['lat'];
            $lon = $row['lon'];


            echo $lat.",".$lon."#";

        }
    }else{
        echo "0";
    }

    mysqli_close($dbc);
```

Also in most cases i do not have problems but for some values of lat and lon i get nothing back when i should have retrieve something!

Comment: what is the php code that executes this query statement ? may be you are missing something there ?

Comment: This question is impossible to answer in its current form. There's way more to the story here. I suggest you echo out the contents of `$query` from the php. What are the datatypes of the columns referenced in the where clause? How is it you are determining that the query is returning NULL? (Does that mean one row that contains all NULL values? Because that's an odd return; we'd expect either that MySQL encountered an error, or that MySQL would return a resultset,  possibly and empty rowset.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the query text (from an `echo "query=".$query;` immediately preceding the mysqli_query call, which has lat and lon values which don't return any rows. (Is it possible that `$right>$left` or `$bottom>$top`. Have you verified that the values aren't getting converted to scientific notation in the query text e.g. `1.40302012E+02`  where what you really wanted to send to MySQL was `140.302012` ?